# Communication between two or more Java applications using Redis

Tags: java, redis, communication

I am trying to communicate between multiple instances of the same Java application using Redis at the moment.

Currently, I use a pubsub channel, if one instance sends a message, I register it in a Map with an UUID and Consumer to handle the response once other instances reply.

This code however is kind of ugly though and far from optimal. I was wondering if there is any other way to do a similar thing.

In short, what would be the best way to have communication between applications that require all connected instances to reply?

An example of use would be with 5 instances for example (instance1-5) and I send a call that requires every application to send their active connections so I can list a total of all connections. My current implementation is not able to do such a thing as it only allows for single responses. What I want is wait for all "connected" instances to reply (with timeout probably) and only then to respond to the Callback.

(I can change my current implementation to get this to work, but I am wondering if there are better alternatives to the Redis pub/sub channels I am currently using | Redis however is preferable as the users of this application will have a redis server already available)